# Mysql getting weekly report between 2 dates

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I need to get number of users registered in a week, given start date and end date.
Right now the logic used is:

```
week_days_list = [['2017-01-01', '2017-01-07'], ['2017-01-08', '2017-01-14']]

for week in week_days_list:
   query = 'SELECT COUNT('*') AS `__count` FROM `user_table`
            INNER JOIN `user_auth` ON (`user_table`.`user_id` = `user_auth`.`id` ) 
            WHERE `user_auth`.`date_joined` BETWEEN week[0] 
            AND week[1];'
```

Result is:

---

__count

15

---

I want it to reduce it to 1 query.
Eg:

---

Week Interval         |  count

'2017-01-01'     |   15

'2017-01-08'     |   12

---

Answer (score 0):

Going by the fact you consider week 1 of 2017 to be 2017-01-01 to 2017-01-07, you can do it with something like the following:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(date_joined) `__year`,
    WEEK(date_joined) `__week`,
    COUNT(*)          `__count`
FROM
    user_table
JOIN
    user_auth ON
        user_table.user_id = user_auth.id
GROUP BY
    YEAR(date_joined),
    WEEK(date_joined)
```

I should note that this is completely untested.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the __range operator:

...filter(current_issue__isnull=True, created_at__range=(start_date, end_date))
```